# How to implement timer into Automatically image slide inside the fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter, timertask

How to implement timer into Automatically image slide inside the fragment? 
I used Fragment and CustomSwipeAdapter and I dont know where to put the timer to make the images automatically slide. Is it inside the Fragment or in CustomSwipe Adpater?

This is for the Fragment:

```
public class PrimaryFragment extends Fragment {


    public static ViewPager viewPager1;

    CustomSwipeAdapter adapter;
    public PrimaryFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }

   private String[] health ={"Abdominal Disorder","Abrasion","Aches","Anxiety","Bruises","Burns or Scalds","Constipation","Coughs" +
            "","Cramps","Diarrhea","Dizziness","Dyspepsia","Epilepsy","Fever","Gastric Problem" +
            "","High Blood Pressure","Hydrophobia","Tonsillitis"};


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    }

    @Nullable

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.primary_layout,null);
        //((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("First Aid and Survival Tips");



        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.primary_layout,container,false);

        viewPager1 = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        adapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this.getActivity());
        viewPager1.setAdapter(adapter);


        ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.oneListView);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,health);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),health[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(position == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), abdominal.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if(position == 1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), abrasion.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if(position == 2) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), aches.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if(position == 3) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), allergies.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if(position == 4) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), bruises.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if(position == 5) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), burns.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if(position == 6) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), constipation.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if(position == 7) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), coughs.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if(position == 8) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), cramps.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if(position == 9) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), diarrhea.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
               // if(position == 10) {
               //     Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), digestive.class);
                 //   startActivity(intent);
              //  }
                if(position == 10) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), dizziness.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if(position == 11) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), dyspepsia.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if(position == 12) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), epilepsy.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if(position == 13) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), fever.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if(position == 14) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), gastric.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if(position == 15) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), highblood.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if(position == 16) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), hydrophobia.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if(position == 17) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), tonsilitis.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }}
```

CustomSwipeAdapter

```
 public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private int[] image_resource = {R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three};
    private Context ctx;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CustomSwipeAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return image_resource.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == (LinearLayout)object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        /*TextView textView = (TextView)  item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_count);*/
        imageview.setImageResource(image_resource[position]);
       /* textView.setText("" + position);*/
        container.addView(item_view);
        return item_view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }

}
```

Comment: I used a Library. This one here https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider Be careful with memory leak, working with images is always difficult.

Comment: that has to be the most frightening string array assignment I've ever seen :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Handler h = new Handler();
int delay = 15000; //1 second
Runnable runnable;
private int[] pagerIndex = {-1};
@Override
public void onStart() {


    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           pagerIndex[0]++;
    if (pagerIndex[0] >= adapter.getCount()) {
        pagerIndex[0] = 0;
    }

    viewPager.setCurrentItem(pagerIndex[0]);
            runnable=this;

            h.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
        }
    }
    , delay);

    super.onStart();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could start a timed task in you `Fragment`.
Haven't verified this code yet, but it should work fine.
Create your swipe task :

```
final long delay = 2000;
Handler handler = new Handler();
private int[] pagerIndex = {-1};
private Runnable swipeTask = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        pagerIndex[0]++;
        if (pagerIndex[0] >= adapter.getCount()) {
            pagerIndex[0] = 0;
        }

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(pagerIndex[0]);
        handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
};
```

And in your fragment's `onCreateView()`, after the viewPager, adapter etc have been set,

```
task.run();
```

Comment: The postDelayed has an error.  Cannot resolve method (anonymous java.lang .Runnable,long)

Comment: @Candy083 Handler should be android.os.Handler, not java.util.logging.Handler

Answer (score 0):

```
private int currentPage = 0;
final long DELAY = 1000;//delay in milliseconds before auto sliding starts.
final long PERIOD = 4000; //time in milliseconds between sliding.

private void autoScroll(){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (currentPage == YourImageList.size()) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
        }
    };

    timer = new Timer(); // creating a new thread
    timer .schedule(new TimerTask() { // task to be scheduled

        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(Update);
        }
    }, DELAY_MS, PERIOD_MS);
}
```

> Call autoScroll() in onCreateView() of your fragment, **after** your view pager adapter is set.

```
viewPager.setAdapter(ViewPagerAdapter)
autoScroll()
```

> If you have to change between fragments, remember to **cancel** timer in **onDetach()** method of your fragment as shown below to avoid any issues.

```
 @Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    if(timer != null) {
       timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
}
```

> Hope this will help someone. Since I personally experienced an issue with sliding when moving to another fragment and coming back to the same fragment since I had not cancel the timer before moving to another fragment.